# Что такое в keyframes entry и exit?

Tags: css, css3, google-chrome, keyframes, animation-timeline

В демо [демонстрации](https://scroll-driven-animations.style/demos/contact-list/css/) Chrome нашёл такой код:

```css
@supports(animation-timeline: view()) {
            @keyframes fade-in-on-enter--fade-out-on-exit {
                entry 0%  {
                    opacity: 0;
                    transform: translateY(100%);
                }
                entry 100%  {
                    opacity: 1;
                    transform: translateY(0);
                }
                exit 0% {
                    opacity: 1;
                    transform: translateY(0);
                }
                exit 100% {
                    opacity: 0;
                    transform: translateY(-100%);
                }
            }

            #list-view > ul > li {
                animation: linear fade-in-on-enter--fade-out-on-exit;
                animation-timeline: view();
            }
        }
```

Я нигде не нашёл информации о `entry` и `exit` словах, кто знает, что это такое?

Рабочий пример (Chrome 117)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#list-view {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul {
  counter-reset: index;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#list-view {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  height: 5em;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  counter-increment: index;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

li .name::after {
  content: " (item #" counter(index) ")";
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

li .name {
    flex: 1;
}

li .avatar {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-size: 100%;
}

@supports(animation-timeline: view()) {
  @keyframes fade-in-on-enter--fade-out-on-exit {
    entry 0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    entry 100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    exit 0% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    exit 100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
  }
  
  #list-view>ul>li {
    animation: linear fade-in-on-enter--fade-out-on-exit;
    animation-timeline: view();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="list-view">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Adam Argyle</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Adriana Jara</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Andre Bandarra</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Alexandra White</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Ali Spivak</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Anusmita Ray</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Barry Pollard</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Bramus Van Damme</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Brendan Kenny</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Carol Rivero</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Eiji Kitamura</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Ewa Gasperowicz</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">François Beaufort</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jack J</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jake Archibald</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jecelyn Yeen</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jeremy Wagner</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Joe Medley</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Kevin Lee</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Marc Doerrenhaus</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Mariko Kosaka</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Maud Nalpas</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Matthias Rohmer</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Milica Mihajlija</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Oliver Dunk</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Patrick Kettner</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Paul Kinlan</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Pete LePage</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Philip Walton</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Rachel Andrew</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Rick Viscomi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Robert Nyman</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Rowan Merewood</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Sam Dutton</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Sebastian Benz</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Sofia Emelianova</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Thomas Steiner</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Una Kravets</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-range

Comment: @andreymal но ни слова о keyframes

Comment: Зато в [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) есть слово об animation-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ситуация становится понятнее, если анимировать `entry` по одной оси, а `exit` по другой.

Я решил анимировать

- для `entry` - ось x
- для `exit` - ось y

При прокрутке контейнера

- элементы из низа анимируются по правилу `entry`
- элемента из верха анимируются по правилу `exit`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#list-view {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
  counter-reset: index;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#list-view {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  height: 5em;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  counter-increment: index;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

li .name::after {
  content: " (item #" counter(index) ")";
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

li .name {
    flex: 1;
}

li .avatar {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-size: 100%;
}

@supports(animation-timeline: view()) {
  @keyframes fade-in-on-enter--fade-out-on-exit {
    entry 0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    entry 100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    exit 0% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    exit 100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
  }
  
  #list-view>ul>li {
    animation: linear fade-in-on-enter--fade-out-on-exit;
    animation-timeline: view();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="list-view">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Adam Argyle</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Adriana Jara</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Andre Bandarra</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Alexandra White</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Ali Spivak</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Anusmita Ray</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Barry Pollard</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Bramus Van Damme</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Brendan Kenny</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Carol Rivero</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Eiji Kitamura</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Ewa Gasperowicz</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">François Beaufort</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jack J</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jake Archibald</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jecelyn Yeen</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Jeremy Wagner</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Joe Medley</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Kevin Lee</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Marc Doerrenhaus</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Mariko Kosaka</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Maud Nalpas</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Matthias Rohmer</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Milica Mihajlija</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Oliver Dunk</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Patrick Kettner</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Paul Kinlan</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Pete LePage</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Philip Walton</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Rachel Andrew</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Rick Viscomi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Robert Nyman</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Rowan Merewood</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Sam Dutton</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Sebastian Benz</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Sofia Emelianova</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Thomas Steiner</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Una Kravets</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```